# Firestore - How to aggregate data by time (in this example by hour)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, group-by, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to produce a real time graph like below (sort of like google analytics) on unique visitor graph. 
After some investigation, I notice Firestore does not support GROUP BY like in SQL.

Below in my sample data, no.1 and no.3 is within the same hour but of the same user_id = 1. So it should be counted as 1 and not 2. So, the number of person visited site "pen.com" at 10:00 hour is 1.

How can I aggregate this data for site count unique visits time series, taking this example I am doing by hour grouping user_id ? Is there way to do this, since I see google analytics can do this, even in seconds (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N128o.png)!

Below are the example data and I want to aggregate the data to show the graph like below. The graph I drew is based on this sample data.

tracking <-- collection

```
  (10:00 hour)    

1. document(aaa123) <----------- inside 10:00 hour same place "pen.com"
user_id = 1
site_unique_identifier = "pen.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 10:11

2. document(xyz567)
user_id = 2
site_unique_identifier = "hex.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 10:15

3. document(qqq123) <----------- inside 10:00 hour same place "pen.com"
user_id = 1
site_unique_identifier = "pen.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 10:18

4. document(xyz567)
user_id = 3
site_unique_identifier = "hex.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 10:19

5. document(fff567)
user_id = 4
site_unique_identifier = "hex.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 10:19

  (11:00 hour)    

6. document(xxx123)
user_id = 1
site_unique_identifier = "hex.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 11:21

7. document(zzz123)
user_id = 2
site_unique_identifier = "hex.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 11:22

8. document(ggg123)
user_id = 2
site_unique_identifier = "pen.com"
timestamp = 10/09/2019 11:24
```

Based on the above sample data, below is a time series graph by the hour of unique visitors to various sites. (observe the 10:00 hour visit count is 1 instead of 2 to site "pen.com")

[image: site tracking graph]

output of the query to generate info for the graph (based on the same data):

```
10:00
- pen.com - 1
- hex.com - 3
11:00
- pen.com - 1
- hex.com - 2
```

you could see we are grouping by user_id, site_unique_identifier, hour

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics probably uses BigQuery and not Firestore.

Firestore is a NoSQL database and because of how it is structured, you cannot use group by and similar complexity increasing operators since that is not what is meant to do ([you can check this doc for further understanding at section 3.2 Data Model](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/36971.pdf) ).

For the use case you are describing in your question, I would rather choose a SQL database, like Cloud SQL since is quite structured data.

If you still want to use Firestore for this, maybe you could try with [FireSQL](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/jsayol/firesql/) , but note that there are limitations and that what you want to be may not be possible with it either.

Comment: I'ved dump the idea, until there is a real solution, time-series seems a bit too hard, I believe something they have to seriously look into. Im migrating back to SQL.